# approaches to removing from binary tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I have written a code that removes a node from a binary tree before looking at my study book. Here it is:

```
int max (num*& node) {
    if (node->right != 0) max (node->right);

    else { 
        num* temp = node;
        node = node->left;
        return temp->n;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void remove (num*& node, int k) {
    if (node == 0) {return;}
    if (k == node->n){

    if (node->left == 0){
        num* newleaf = node;
        node = node->right; 
        delete newleaf;
    }
    else if (node->right == 0){
        num* newleaf = node;
        node = node->left; 
        delete newleaf;
    }
    else { 
        node->n = max (node->left);
        }}
    if (k < node->n) {remove (node->left, k);}
    if (k > node->n) {remove (node->right, k);}

}
```

So, what we do is assigning the value of target node to the value of max node in left part without **actually** removing the target node. Then we delete that max node.
Apparently, it works properly and I have checked it with different cases.
But then I took a look at my book and found a different approach:

```
node* find_max (node* p_tree)
{
    if ( p_tree == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ( p_tree->p_right == NULL )
    {
        return p_tree;
    }
    return find_max( p_tree->p_right );
}

node* remove_max_node (node* p_tree, node* p_max_node)
{
    if ( p_tree == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }   
    if ( p_tree == p_max_node )
    {   
        return p_max_node->p_left;
    }
    p_tree->p_right = remove_max_node( p_tree->p_right, p_max_node );
    return p_tree;
}
node* remove (node* p_tree, int key)
{
    if ( p_tree == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ( p_tree->key_value == key )
    {
        if ( p_tree->p_left == NULL )
        {
            node* p_right_subtree = p_tree->p_right;
            delete p_tree
            return p_right_subtree;
        }
        if ( p_tree->p_right == NULL )
        {
            node* p_left_subtree = p_tree->p_left;
            delete p_tree;
            return p_left_subtree;
        }
        node* p_max_node = find_max( p_tree->p_left );
        p_max_node->p_left =
        remove_max_node( p_tree->p_left, p_max_node );
        p_max_node->p_right = p_tree->p_right;
        delete p_tree;
        return p_max_node;
    }
    else if ( key < p_tree->key_value )
    {
        p_tree->p_left = remove( p_tree->p_left, key );
    }
    else
    {
        p_tree->p_right = remove( p_tree->p_right, key );
    }
    return p_tree;
}
```

So, the author **does** delete the target node and replaces it with a max one, then deletes a max node.

I have not found drawbacks in my version. But as I am not that much experienced with trees, I would like to ask you: 
are there disadvantages of my approach? Is author's better? Maybe his one is worse since he uses additional function? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better asked on [**codereview.stackexchange.com**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There are a few drawbacks - your `max` doesn't return a value on every path (so will cause undefined behaviour) and when it does, returns before the delete. I also have a feeling that you didn't test the case of removing the only node from a tree with one node.